# Write text to file in C# with 513 space characters

Tags: c#, notepad++, notepad, writefile, writealltext

Here is a code that writes the string to a file

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("test.txt", "P                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ");
```

It's basically the character 'P' followed by a total of 513 space character.

When I open the file in Notepad++, it appears to be fine. However, when I open in windows Notepad, all I see is garbled characters.

If instead of 513 space character, I add 514 or 512, it opens fine in Notepad.

What am I missing?

Comment: please use `"P" + new string(' ', 513)`

Comment: Notepad is incorrectly detecting the file encoding.  `File.WriteAllText(string,string)` uses UTF-8 by default.

Comment: See [the Notepad file-encoding problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070417-00/?p=27223). If you want to fix the problem, specify UTF-8 and start your file with a BOM.

Comment: @Tigran same result

Comment: @amyn His suggestion wasn't to fix your problem.  It's to shorten your code, because 513 spaces in a string is nuts.

Comment: @amyn: it was for shortness of writing, and not a solution.

Comment: @DourHighArch that's what I wanted. thanks

Comment: `File.WriteAllText(@"test.txt", ("P" + new string(' ', 513)), Encoding.UTF8);`

Comment: @Jimi I already tried that and that does open up fine in Notepad. What I was curious was about the number 513. Doesn't happen with 512 or 514 but 513.

Comment: Have you ever wondered why Notepad is sooo slooow in opening some simple text files which take a fraction of that time to load anywhere else? Your text file begins with `50 20`. Now, is it Unicode (UTF16LE)? Is it the other Unicode (UTF8), the other Unicode (...), Is it ANSI. Anxiety. Better recheck. No wait, lets read the WHOLE file an get the Byte Order Mark then re-encode. Then I'll be sure...

Comment: Notepad's file format detection routine works nearly all the time.  But, not always.  It probably has something to do with the fact that 512 is a nice round number (2 to the 9th).  So, it sees a file that is 514 characters long and sees the last 512 of them as spaces, and figures the first two bytes must be some kind of badly formed byte order mark: (0x50, 0x20) and says "oh well, let me fall off the deep end".  Report it as a bug to Microsoft (but don't hold your breath about getting it fixed).

Comment: @Flydog57  Well, 103 should be enough to throw it off (can't test now, just a guess).

Comment: Forgot to mention: check out what character is Unicode `U+2020`.

Comment: See my answer below. There's nothing magic about 513, just that an odd number of spaces plus the original single character yields an even number of bytes. You're right that 512 and 514 don't duplicate your issue, but other combinations/lengths that result in an even number of _bytes_ reproduce it quite easily.

Answer (score 5):

What you are missing is that Notepad is guessing, and it is not because your length is specifically 513 spaces ... it is because it is an **even number of bytes** and the file size is >= 100 total bytes. Try 511 or 515 spaces ... or 99 ... you'll see the same misinterpretation of your file contents. With an odd number of bytes, Notepad can assume that your file is not any of the double-byte encodings, because those would all result in 2 bytes per character = even number of total bytes in the file. If you give the file a few more low-order ASCII characters at the beginning (e.g., "PICKLE" + spaces), Notepad does a much better job of understanding that it should treat the content as single-byte chars.

The suggested approach of including `Encoding.UTF8` is the easiest fix ... it will write a BOM to the beginning of the file which *tells* Notepad (and Notepad++) what the format of the data is, so that it doesn't have to resort to this guessing behavior (you can see the difference between your original approach and the BOM approach by opening both in Notepad++, then look in the bottom-right corner of the app. With the BOM, it will tell you the encoding is `UTF-8-BOM` ... without it, it will just say `UTF-8`).

I should also say that the *contents* of your file are not 'wrong', per se... the weird format is purely due to Notepad's "guessing" algorithm. So unless it's a requirement that people use Notepad to read your file with 1 letter and a large, odd number of spaces ... maybe just don't sweat it. If you do change to writing the file with `Encoding.UTF8`, then you do need to ensure that any other system that reads your file knows how to honor the BOM, because it **is** a real change to the contents of your file. If you cannot verify that all consumers of your file can/will handle the BOM, then it may be safer to just understand that Notepad happens to make a bad guess for your specific use case, and leave the raw contents exactly how you want them.

You can verify the physical difference in your file with the BOM by doing a binary read and then converting them to a string (you can't "see" the change with `ReadAllText`, because it honors & strips the BOM):

```
byte[] contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("test.txt");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(contents));
```

Comment: Yes, if you aren't telling a program which encoding a text file uses, it is guessing. (Unless there is some standard that applies such as JSON, XML, HTML, …, or other source of this essential information such as project file, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Try passing in a different encoding:

```
i. System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename , stringVariable, Encoding.UTF8);
ii. System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename , stringVariable, Encoding.UTF32);
iii. etc.
```

Also You could try using another way to build your string, to make it be easier to read, change and count, instead of tapping the space bar 513 times;

i. Use the string constructor (like @Tigran suggested)

```
var result = "P" + new String(' ', 513);
```

ii. Use the stringBuilder

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.Append("P");

for (var i = 1; i <= 513; i++) { stringBuilder.Append(" "); }
```

iii. Or both

```
public string AppendSpacesToString(string stringValue, int numberOfSpaces) 
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.Append(stringValue);
    stringBuilder.Append(new String(' ', numberOfSpaces));
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```